# Profiling Django with PyCharm

Tags: python, django, profiling, pycharm

My app is pretty slow even in a dev environment so I would like to figure out what's slowing it down so I can try and fix it.

I know about the debug toolbar and according to what it reports neither the database queries nor the downloaded sources are the issue, so it must be the business logic.

However, I cannot run the PyCharm profiler with the Django server because, well, it's not like running a script.

How may I profile Django with PyCharm?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably set configuration properly.

[image]

Then click on **Edit Configurations...**

[image]

The main thing is to set Interpreter (your virtual environment). You don't have to set **Custom Run Command** if you use `python manage.py runserver`

Then you can run **Django server** directly from **PyCharm** ann **Profiler** too.