# IntelliJ profiling Django application

Tags: python, django, profiling

I am developing a Django application inside IntelliJ. 
Now, I would like to profile it. To see, if some code is run more than it should if some queries are slow,...

All I can find is :

- That exist debug tool that shows DB profile [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770504/profiling-django-with-pycharm)
- Python profiler (like vmprof):

I did install vmprof and I run it. But my problem is, that all code inside all libraries is showed,... I can't find my code inside.. is there a way to configure to show only my code?

Answer (score 1):

I use from time to time the profiling feature from Django Debug Toolbar.

[image]

[image]

It's really easy to use and it provides many more optimization capabilities as showing your database queries, where you can find which ones are repeated and optimize them.

Link to the library https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/